# Google Maps with React Native in iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native

I am new to react native and am trying to add a google map to my app.

I started by installing react-native-maps and creating a new file with the following code.

```js
import React from 'react';
import MapView, { PROVIDER_GOOGLE } from 'react-native-maps';

export default class MapScreen extends React.Component  {  
        render() {    
            return ( 

                <MapView 
                provider={ PROVIDER_GOOGLE }
                style={{flex: 1}} 
                region={{
                    latitude: 54.721344, 
                    longitude: -6.199981
                }} 
                showsUserLocation={true} />
                ); 
                 }
        }
```

After this I added the following code to the Podfile file found in the ios folder.

```rb
target 'MapExample' do
    pod 'Yoga', path: "./node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga/Yoga.podspec"
    pod 'GoogleMaps'
end
```

After getting my api key from google, I opened Xcode and added the AirGoogleMap folder to my project. I then went into my build settings and add 'HAVE_GOOGLE_MAPS+1' to Preprocessor Macros Macros.

Next I went into my AppDelegate.m file and added the following lines

```c
@import GoogleMaps;

[GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"YOUR_API_KEY"]
```

After all this was done I ran my app in the iOS simulator and when I did this an error appeared as shown below.

[image: error]

I am unsure as to why I am getting this error as I have added the AirGoogleMap to my project via Xcode. Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes pod does not work properly so you might be have to build the app from scratch. In your issue what I can suggest you to read the instructions in the link below carefully and create a new project by using `react-native-init` if necessary. Then try it again. Lastly, please be aware of that if you're using pod and when you open the project with xCode, Libraries section should be empty and Target/Build Phases/Link Binary With Libraries should contain generally and mostly only `libPods-projectname.a`

https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/installation.md

Comment: ended up it was a problem with the profile file inside the iOS folder

Answer (score 0):

You can't use import outside a module, also try to restart the entire simulation engine.